# Using Perl/Moose, what happens to the value returned by modifiers?

Tags: perl, return-value, moose, modifier

Learning perl I just recently discovered the wonders of Moose!

I'm trying to wrap my head around modifiers -- or at least how the return values are handled... do they get stored someplace?

```
{package Util::Printable;

use Moose::Role;

  requires 'to_str','init';

  before 'to_str' => sub {
      my($self) = @_;
      $self->{to_string} = "my string thing";
      return $self->{to_string}; 
  };

  after 'init' => sub{
    my($self) = @_;
    $self->{roles} = __PACKAGE__;
    $self->{is_printable} = 1;
  };


}
1;
__END__
```

**Using the Printable Role**

```
{package MonkeyPrint;
use Moose;

with 'Util::Printable';


  sub init{
    my($self) = @_;
    return 1;
  };

  sub BUILD{
    my($self) = @_;
    $self->init();  
  }


  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------ # 
  # Printable Support
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
  use overload '""' => 'to_str';  

  sub to_str {
      my($self) = @_;
      $self->{to_string} = __PACKAGE__;
      return $self->{to_string}; 
  };


 __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
}
1;
__END__
```

Comment: Cosmetic note: you don't need braces around your `package` block.  `package` means "all that comes after will be in such package."  As you'll usually stick to a single package per file, there'll be no anbiguity.  Note that since 5.14 you can also use a `package Util::Printable { contents }` syntax that's more in line with the other namespaced curly-bracket languages.  Whether the new syntax will displace the current common practice is yet to observe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say a method has a `before` and an `after` wrapper.

1. The `before` code is called.
2. Its return value is ignored/discarded.
3. The original method is called.
4. It's value is saved.
5. The `after` code is called.
6. Its return value is ignored/discarded.
7. The saved value is returned.

Use `around` if you need to alter or replace the value returned by the original method.